# setImageBitmap Error, ImageView call OutOfMemory

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

Project with error on GitHub: https://github.com/MediaPortal1/HowToDraw/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/poltavets/app/

I had method img.setImageResources(R.id.image) in my project, but it offten call OutOfmemory when i use this method often or change screen orientation.
I found this article about loading bitmap images "right": https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
Copy-paste 2 last methods of this article, and change my code from:

```
       imageView.setImageResource(image);
```

TO:

```
 Handler handler=new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if(getRequestedOrientation()==ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), msg.what,100,100));
                else imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), msg.what,400,400));
            }
        };
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(image);
```

I put this methods to Handler and it was work faster. And i add conditions of orientation, because in land-orietation ImageView is smaller and bitmap must have smaller resolution. It worked fine, everithink was ok. But i worked with another details in this project(just add images to my project), and re-build this project 2-3 times and OutOfMemory error appears again when i start my activity. Before this error arose not always, but now its arose ALWAYS when I start Activity! How? I dont toush code of this activity? My images is realy low-momory. Max size of images 200kb. How image with size 100kb can call OutOfMemory?

Error:

```
Process: com.poltavets.app.howtodraw, PID: 28720    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 35389452 byte allocation with 5482128 free bytes and 5MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:655)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:488)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:511)
    at com.poltavets.app.howtodraw.view.HowTo.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(HowTo.java:224)
    at com.poltavets.app.howtodraw.view.HowTo$3.handleMessage(HowTo.java:185)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

Code of ChangeImage(Error is here):

```
    public void changeImageSrc(int image,int count,int position,String name) {
            filename=name+"_"+image+"_"+position;
            imagenumber=position;
            if(move!=null || back!=null) {
                move.setEnabled(false);
                back.setEnabled(false);
            }
            Handler handler=new Handler(){
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    if(getRequestedOrientation()==ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), msg.what,100,100));

 else imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), msg.what,400,400)); // OUT OF MEMORY ERROR
                }
            };
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(image);

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_how_to) + " " + name + ": " + (position+1)+"/"+(count));
                if(position==0 || position+1==count){
                    if(position==0){
                        findViewById(R.id.backBtn).setEnabled(false);
                        findViewById(R.id.backBtn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    else {
                        findViewById(R.id.moveBtn).setEnabled(false);
                        findViewById(R.id.moveBtn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.finish),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    showNavButtons();
                }
            if(move!=null || back!=null) {
                move.setEnabled(true);
                back.setEnabled(true);
            }
```

2 methods from google article:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did nothing. I re-builded this project 3-4 times, but it didn't help. But i just re-build it now with no changes, and it worked.

Comment: Please don't swear in your answers.

Comment: it seems like you need to often clean/rebuild projects when manipulating with images in the app. I included 3 images in the app (they had ~1.5mb together) and the app crashed. No matter what I did (I managed to reduce their size to 50kb) it didn't help. After I clean/rebuilt the project everything suddenly worked (with smaller images ofc). 
I guess the cached images were used before clean/rebuild and thus it didn't really matter how I optimized the images.